# Implementing Dijkstra's algorithm using min-heap but failed

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, shortest-path, dijkstra

I am trying to implement `Dijkstra's Algorithm` using min-heap in java but getting wrong output every time. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2657086/1175065) i fount the same topic in C++. Below is my graph. Node A, which is green colored, is source and Node F, which is red colored, is destination. My objective is to find out the shortest path length from A to F.

[image: This is my graph]

Below is my code

```
public class Dijkstra {
    private static Heap heap = new Heap();
    private static int[][] graph;

    public Dijkstra() {
        graph = new int[6][6];
        /*
         * The graph value assignment is just for checking the code. node A is
         * referred as node 0, node B is referred as node 1 and so on. finally
         * node F is referred as node 5.
         */
        graph[0][0] = graph[0][1] = graph[0][3] = graph[0][4] = graph[0][5] = graph[1][0] = graph[1][1] = graph[1][4] = graph[1][5] = graph[2][2] = graph[2][5] = graph[3][0] = graph[3][3] = graph[4][0] = graph[4][1] = graph[4][4] = graph[5][0] = graph[5][1] = graph[5][2] = graph[5][5] = 0;
        graph[1][2] = graph[2][1] = graph[2][3] = graph[3][2] = graph[3][4] = graph[4][3] = graph[4][5] = graph[5][4] = 1;
        graph[1][3] = graph[3][1] = 3;
        graph[0][2] = graph[2][0] = 4;
        graph[2][4] = graph[4][2] = 5;
        graph[3][5] = graph[5][3] = 8;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dijkstra dij = new Dijkstra();
        // Source is node A (node 0) and destination is node F (node 5)
        System.out.println(dij.solve(6, 0, 5));
    }

    public int solve(int numOfNodes, int source, int dest) {
        heap.push(source, 0);
        while (!heap.isEmpty()) {
            int u = heap.pop();
            if (u == dest)
                return heap.cost[dest];
            for (int i = 0; i < numOfNodes; i++) {
                if (graph[u][i] >= 0)
                    heap.push(i, heap.cost[u] + graph[u][i]);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}

class Heap {
    private int[] data;
    private int[] index;
    public int[] cost;
    private int size;

    public Heap() {
        data = new int[6];
        index = new int[6];
        cost = new int[6];

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            index[i] = -1;
            cost[i] = -1;
        }

        size = 0;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return (size == 0);
    }

    private void shiftUp(int i) {
        int j;
        while (i > 0) {
            j = (i - 1) / 2;
            if (cost[data[i]] < cost[data[j]]) {
                // swap here
                int temp = index[data[i]];
                index[data[i]] = index[data[j]];
                index[data[j]] = temp;
                // swap here
                temp = data[i];
                data[i] = data[j];
                data[j] = temp;
                i = j;
            } else
                break;
        }
    }

    private void shiftDown(int i) {
        int j, k;
        while (2 * i + 1 < size) {
            j = 2 * i + 1;
            k = j + 1;
            if (k < size && cost[data[k]] < cost[data[j]]
                    && cost[data[k]] < cost[data[i]]) {
                // swap here
                int temp = index[data[k]];
                index[data[k]] = index[data[i]];
                index[data[i]] = temp;
                // swap here
                temp = data[k];
                data[k] = data[i];
                data[i] = temp;

                i = k;
            } else if (cost[data[j]] < cost[data[i]]) {
                // swap here
                int temp = index[data[j]];
                index[data[j]] = index[data[i]];
                index[data[i]] = temp;
                // swap here
                temp = data[j];
                data[j] = data[i];
                data[i] = temp;

                i = j;
            } else
                break;
        }
    }

    public int pop() {
        int res = data[0];
        data[0] = data[size - 1];
        index[data[0]] = 0;
        size--;
        shiftDown(0);
        return res;
    }

    public void push(int x, int c) {
        if (index[x] == -1) {
            cost[x] = c;
            data[size] = x;
            index[x] = size;
            size++;
            shiftUp(index[x]);
        } else {
            if (c < cost[x]) {
                cost[x] = c;
                shiftUp(index[x]);
                shiftDown(index[x]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While running this whole code, i am getting 0 as output but one can clearly tell the cost from node A to node F is 7 (4+1+1+1 = A-C-D-E-F). Where is the error?

Comment: you can remove line graph[0][0] = graph[0][1] = ... because they will be 0 by default

Comment: You've set a lot of edges to having zero weight, so the shortest path is 0.  If you set those edges to -1 then your  'if (graph[u][i] >= 0)' statement will catch those properly.

Comment: Also, when you pop a node you need to check that you haven't already evaluated it, otherwise you might never terminate.

Comment: @RunningWild: Sir can you please explain me a bit more. How can i check that poped element is already evaluated?

Comment: @RaviJoshi: Keep an array of as many booleans as your graph has nodes, all initially false.  When you pop a node, first check if its boolean in that array is true, if so then pop the next element, otherwise mark its boolean as true so you don't evaluate it the next time.

Answer (score 4):

You test for an existing edge using `graph[u][i] >= 0`. But your graph is defined to have no edge for value zero. So you should change it to

```
if (graph[u][i] > 0) ...
```

inside method `solve`. Another possibility is to mark non-existing edges with a value of `-1` in your matrix. This would then also allow for zero-cost edges.

Comment: Yeah.... Absolutely correct. now working fine. There are three integer array in `heap` class. Is it possible to reduced `heap` code further?

Answer (score 0):

In the heap, you have two values:
index that identifies the node,
and cost that identify the distance of the node.
You pop the cost, that is the distance, but you used it like the index to identify the node.

```
public int pop() {
        int res = data[0];
        ...
        return res;
    }
```

and in solve():

```
  int u = heap.pop();
  if (u == dest)
  ...
```